# stringr::str_view() not displaying anything in the "Viewer" tab

Tags: html, r, rstudio, stringr

I've just updated the new version of R (version 4.2.3-Shortstop Beagle) and R-studio (2023.3.0.386-Cherry Blossom). Now, whenever I use the function `stringr::str_view()` instead of the traditional view in the plots pane, it only displays a result on the console:

```
text <- "Hello 123"
stringr::str_view(text, "H")

[1] │ <H>ello 123
```

And what I will like to see is the traditional pane:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking, and you previously needed to install the package `htmlwidgets`. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `html` parameter as `TRUE`.